# How to detect Facial Sideview Left ear, Sideview Nose, Sideview mouth in iOS Application using OpenCV?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, image-processing

I need help with face profiling through image in an iOS application.

I am trying to detect left ear, nose and mouth in a given image. So far I tried OpenCV, I found voila's haar classifiers but this haar classifier does not detect left ear.

I need to perform this detection without going to server/online.

Is OpenCV good choice for this? Any sample codes you can share to achieve this functionality would be great.

What can be other choices to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by 'they dont detect left ear'? Have you tried flipping your image?

Comment: @Derman this haar classifier does not detect left ear. the video that voila jones are mentioning detect ear in same orientation as I do.

Comment: If you have training samples, things should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 6):

I think only using part templates (e.g., viola's haar-classifiers) will not work in your case. The parts you want to detect are very small and will be fully/partially occluded most of the time. My suggestion would be to use graphical models based methods, i.e., active appearance models, pictorial structures, etc. This will not only allow you to exploit spatial constraints (i.e, mouth should be always below nose, etc.), but also works when one or few of the parts are occluded. Probably you can start with following publicly available codes:

1. http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/index.php#structclass
2. http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~gall/projects/facialfeatures/facialfeatures.html

Both codes are in C++, and will allow you to detect facial body parts, but I think ears are not included in both. May be you can try adding additional parts by slightly modifying the source code, and also training your own part-templates for the missing parts.

PS. I am not an iOS developer, so I am not sure if iOS can afford such models, but on normal computers they are sufficiently real time for normal size images.

Comment: OpenCV is compatible with iOS as long as you're using Objective-C++. It takes some tinkering to get right, but definitely works.

Comment: Yes, OpenCV can surely work with iOS, but I meant I am not sure if Iphone's processor can afford such models, and can run them in real-time. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: From my tests, OpenCV can afford such models (Although you might have to make your own cascade data), and it may not run on every frame. Some logic for skipping frames to keep it smooth might be needed

Comment: Came here in 2019 and found that the links no longer work.. :(